# Add "delete confirmation prompt" in Thunar

Tags: scripts, delete, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

Thunar does not have the option of a prompt asking for confirmation when moving files to trash (this is, when pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key). I want to add one.

The only way I can think of doing this by creating a new "Custom action", which accepts scripts and binaries (in the "Command" option, below):

[image]

Maybe I can create a script file that executes the delete after a confirmatory prompt. Once that is done, the rest is easy: just link that action to the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

But the truth is I have no idea how to start. I actually don't know if this is the best approach. Maybe there is a better one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put whatever you want for the name and description, but here's the command part:

```
zenity --question --text="Are you sure you want to delete %F?" && rm -rf %F
```

It shows a dialog asking the user whether they want to delete the file(s) and if so, it deletes it. Also, if you just wanted to move the files to the trash, since Thunar already asks when you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, then use this:

```
zenity --question --text="Are you sure you want to move %F to the trash?" && gio trash %F
```

Lastly, be sure to click on the "Appearance Conditions" tab and check all the file types so that the action won't just appear on text files

[image]

To enable the keyboard shortcut for this action, proceed as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/803703/308164). Basically, in the file `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm`, edit the corresponding custom action, so that it looks like this:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1484038296058938-2" "Delete")
```

Comment: **Update**: *gio trash* instead of *gvfs-trash*